What is the proper form of universal instantiation?
Definitions
C is a specific constant iff ∃! x [x=C]
C is a general constant iff ∀x [x=C]
C is an arbitrary constant iff ∀x [x=C] ∨ ∃! x [x=C]
Consider the commonly accepted form of the rule of inference, universal instantiation.
Universal Instantiation UI
∀x [P(x)]; therefore P(x_n), where x_n is any specific individual constant.
There are an unlimited number of specific individual constants: x1,x2,x3,..
Since x_n is any specific individual constant we may say
x1=x_n ∧ x2=x_n ∧ x3=x_n ∧...
By the definition of general constant, x_n is a general constant.
Now we apply modal logic, and ask "is it necessary that the instantiation constant be a general constant, or merely possible?". If there is another possibility, then it isn't necessary that the instantiation constant be a general constant.
Definition
∀x[P(x)]=P(x1) ∧ P(x2) ∧ P(x3) ∧...
Now consider the following demonstration.

∀x [P(x)]
P(x1) ∧ P(x2) ∧... ∧ P(x_i) ∧... [1; Df]
P(x_i) ∧... [2; i-1 applications of simp2]
P(x_i) [3; simp1]

Therefore we have a derivation from ∀x [P(x)] of P(x_i), where x_i denotes a single specific individual.  That means x_i is a specific individual constant, symbolically ∃! x [x=x_i].  Therefore the universal Instantiation constant isn't necessarily a general constant, since it's possible it's a specific constant.  Therefore it appears to me that we must have
Universal Instantiation
∀x [P(x)]; therefore P(α), where α is an arbitrary constant.
Is there anything wrong with this?
EDIT- I was asked to give the formation rules of the the propositional calculus and its extension to first order logic.
Simple statement symbols are capital letters chosen from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts, whose intended interpretation are to be noncompound statements .

Any simple statement symbol is a Wff.
If any formula P is a Wff, then ~(P) is a Wff.
If any formulas P,Q are wffs, then (P ∧ Q) is a Wff.

No formula of the propositional calculus is a Wff unless its being so follows from these rules.
P is a compound statement iff there are wffs A,B such that A ≠ B and P = (A ∧ B) or P = ~(A ∧ B).
P is a simple statement iff P isn't a compound statement.
There are three definitions in Rosser's system RS for the propositional calculus.
Df. (P ∨ Q) = ~(~P ∧ ~Q)
Df. (P → Q) = ~(P ∧ ~Q)
Df. (P ↔ Q) = (P → Q) ∧ (Q → P)
We define the term statement recursively.

Any Wff is a statement.
If P,Q are statements, then (P ∨ Q), (P → Q), and (P ↔ Q) are statements.

No formula of RS is a statement of RS unless its being so follows from these rules.
The formation rules for a well formed formula of Rosser's system for the first order function calculus RS_1 are significantly more complicated.
According to Irving M. Copi's 'Symbolic Logic', the logistic system RS_1 contains infinitely many primitive symbols of the following categories.

Infinitely many propositional constants, with and without subscripts from the first part of the alphabet, and on the system's intended interpretation will be noncompound statements.

Infinitely many propositional variables, with and without subscripts from the middle part of the alphabet, and on the system's intended interpretation will be statement variables that must be instantiated by wffs of RS_1.


Symbols of the first two categories are propositional symbols.

Infinitely many capital letters from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts, having right-hand superscripts '1', '2', '3',... These are predicate constants, and on the system's intended interpretation each of them will designate a particular attribute or binary relation or ternary relation... or n-ary relation according as it's right-hand superscript is '1','2','3',... or 'n'.

Infinitely many capital letters from the middle part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts having right-hand superscripts.  These are predicate variables, and on the system's intended interpretation will be symbols for which names of particular attributes, binary relations, ternary relations,... n-ary relations can be substituted.


Symbols of the third and fourth categories are predicate symbols.

Infinitely many lowercase letters from the first part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts.  These are specific individual constants, and on the system's intended interpretation will be proper names of individuals.

Infinitely many lowercase letters from the latter part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts.  These are individual variables, and on the system's intended interpretation will be variables that can be instantiated by specific individual constants.


Symbols of the fifth and sixth categories are individual symbols.

Logical symbols: ∀, ~, ∧,(,),[,]

In addition to the primitive symbols we introduce some defined symbols into our object language RS_1.
Df. P ∨ Q = ~(~P ∧ ~Q)
Df. P → Q = ~(P ∧ ~Q)
Df. P ↔ Q = (P → Q) ∧ (Q → P)
Df. ∃x [P] = ~∀x [~P]
We define Wff of RS_1 by the following recursive rules:
(α)

If F is a propositional symbol, then F is a Wff.
If F is an n-ary predicate symbol and x1,x2,...,xn are individual symbols, then F(x1,x2,...,xn) is a Wff.

(β)

If F is a Wff, then ~(F) is a Wff.
If F,G are wffs, then (F)∧(G) is a Wff.
If F is a Wff and x is an individual variable, then ∀x [F] is a Wff.

No formula of RS_1 is a Wff unless its being so follows from these rules, or these rules together with the defined symbols.
Since wffs of RS_1 can have free variables, they aren't necessarily statements.  A statement of RS_1 is a Wff with no free variables.
To adapt RS_1 to the logistic system FOL_1, you need arbitrary constants.

Lowercase Greek letters with and without subscripts chosen from the first part of the alphabet.  These will be arbitrary individual constants, and on their intended interpretation will designate any individual or exactly one individual.

Uppercase Greek letters chosen from the middle part of the alphabet, with and without subscripts, and on their intended interpretation will designate any predicate or exactly one predicate.


We define Wff of FOL_1 as follows:

Any Wff of RS_1 is a Wff of FOL_1.

If α1, α2,..., αn are arbitrary individual constants, and Φ is an arbitrary predicate constant then Φ(α1, α2,..., αn) is a Wff.


No formula of FOL_1 is a Wff unless its being so follows from these rules.
We define statement of FOL_1, as any Wff of FOL_1 with no free variables.

∀x [x=C] only holds on a domain with at most one element, "general constant" is non-sensical like Locke's "general triangle, "neither oblique nor rectangle, neither equilateral, equicrural, nor scalenon, but all and none of these at once."

I do not agree with (1) and (2). A constant is designated as such, rather than implied by a criterion. “There exists uniquely an x such that x = c” is trivially true: x is a variable; its value must be c. This is not different from saying there exists an x such that x = c. Constants have to be “unique” by definition, but that is not what “unique” is commonly used to mean: one often says that there exists uniquely an x such that P(x). I think this is why logicians keep equality separate from relation symbols; it acts differently. If (2) were true, the only constant you have in the language is c

@conifold, prove that the domain contains one individual.  It doesn't.  You will need transitivity of equality, which isn't generally true.  If C is a general constant you cannot use if x1=C and x2=C, then x1=x2, because C must be a specific constant in order for transitivity of equality to hold.  I can prove this using Hao Wang's axiom of Identity.

“Is there anything wrong with this” - start by formalizing the first few lines. There are specific rules about how quantifiers may be applied. Try to justify why your language allows forming those formulae. What are the term- and formula-formation rules?

“prove that the domain contains one individual.” If by “for all x” you mean all x in domain D, then “for all x, x = c” means “go through every element in domain D, one by one, and you will find that they are all c”. Since every element is c, the only element is c.

@JuliusHamilton you need transitivity of equality to draw your conclusion, but you can't use it if C is a general constant.  Transitivity of equality only holds if C is a specific constant.  I can PROVE this.  My primary language contains no variables.  Every FOL statement has an equivalent propositional calculus statement that is variable free.

@leepappas Equality is transitive in basically every convention. If you want to describe a relation that isn't transitive, pick a symbol for it that's not "=".

@causative, you must be unaware of Hao Wang's axiom of Identity, from which transitivity of equality is proved.  You want to use A = B, only when A,B are specific constants, but Hao Wang's axiom allows you to consider the case where A or B is an arbitrary constant.

Too many constants: general, specific, arbitrary. A constant is the name of an object. If you have a new logical theory to be discussed, the best thing is to introduce the "philosophical" concepts on which you want to base it and then introduce the relevant formalism. If you use the usual symbols of predicate logic without modification, we will interpret them as usual, in which case the reference will be every math logic textbook.

@Mauro, you need the three classes of constants to prove transitivity of equality isn't true in general.

Yes, well said Mauro. @leepappas Can you let me know if you can join this chat room? https://plato.zulipchat.com/ This seems like a question that can benefit from a lot of back and forth conversation.

Actually here’s an invitation link (no expiration time, can be used by anyone) https://plato.zulipchat.com/join/jrhlppmn3ctw3nxay2qpp5wi/

I think I understand it slightly better. Instead of variables, you have something called a “general constant”. You express that “it can range over all values” by saying that it is in fact equal to all of them - it represents them all. Whereas a specific constant is one that is only equal to one value. I think maybe we could reformulate this in set theory, to better effect.

@JuliusHamilton, yes instead of variables I want to use "general constant".  You see what I am trying to do.

You say, "C is a general constant iff ∀x [x=C]" but in standard logics, the only thing this says is that the domain of interpretation contains a single value, C. You seem to think you can use this formula to mean something like "for all values, x, C can be used to represent x", but that's just not what the notation means and it's not clear that such a meaning can even be part of a consistent logic. You yourself note that equality cannot be transitive in a language with such constants, though transitivity is an essential character of equality; no one is going to accept such a notion of equality. It's even worse than that: for any predicate P, as long as there is at least one value a such that P(a) and at least one value b such that ~P(b), then in your logic, P(C)&~P(C)--which is a contradiction. The logic is inherently inconsistent.
But suppose you could come up with a semantics to make this notion coherent and consistent, then what is it's value? What expressiveness does it add to existing notation?

Actually plenty of people adhere to intransitive views of identity (they just deny classical identity)

@randomindividual, who says identity is intransitive?

Technically there should be no problem in the conclusion since the very definition of an arbitrary constant that you presented entails that it is implied by both a specific constant and a general constant. (It is arbitrary iff it is specific or general, so if it is specific then it is specific or general, and if it is general then it is specific or general.)

Yep, just run a bulldozer over everything and all your problems are at an end.
